# VueJS: 'Property or method is not defined on the instance' - even though method is defined on instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to dynamically bind the class 'adjust' based on the truthiness of a computed value "`isTrueSet`" in Vue.js. I continue to get the error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "itTrueSet" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Task> at src/components/Task.vue
     <TaskList> at src/components/TaskList.vue
       <TaskTracker> at src/components/TaskTracker.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

"`isTrueSet`" is a computed property on the instance, so I am confused why I am receiving this error message.

Any guidance as to why this is happening I would be very grateful.

My single file component looks as follows:

My template code looks like this:

*src/components/Task.vue*

```
<template>
  <div
    class="task-wrapper"
    :style="style"
    :class="[isTrueSet ? 'adjust' : '', editTask ? 'editTask' : '']"
  >
    <div class="left-task-content" :class="{ adjust: itTrueSet }">
      <h1 class="task-height task-title">
        {{ title }}
      </h1>
      <h2 class="task-date">{{ momentDate }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="right-task-content">
      <font-awesome-icon
        @click="toggleRemider"
        class="fa-spacer"
        icon="bell"
      ></font-awesome-icon>
      <font-awesome-icon
        @click="askToUpdateTask(id)"
        class="fa-spacer"
        icon="edit"
      ></font-awesome-icon>
      <font-awesome-icon
        @click="askToDeleteTask(id)"
        class="fa-spacer"
        icon="times-circle"
      ></font-awesome-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And my JavaScript looks like this:

*src/components/Task.vue*

```
<script>
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faTimesCircle, faEdit, faBell } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import moment from "moment";
library.add([faTimesCircle, faEdit, faBell]);
export default {
  name: "Task",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      editTask: false,
    };
  },
  props: {
    title: String,
    date: String,
    id: Number,
    reminder: {
      type: String,
      default: "false",
    },
    taskColor: Array,
  },
  computed: {
    isTrueSet: function () {
      if (this.reminder == "true") {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    style: function () {
      return `background-image: linear-gradient(${this.taskColor[0]}, ${this.taskColor[1]}); background-size: cover; `;
    },
    momentDate: function () {
      return moment(this.date).format("MMM Do YYYY");
    },
  },
  methods: {
    askToDeleteTask: function (id) {
      this.$emit("askToDeleteTask2", id);
    },
    askToUpdateTask: function (id) {
      this.$emit("askToUpdateTask2", id);
      if (this.editTask == false) {
        this.editTask = true;
      } else {
        this.editTask = false;
      }
    },
    toggleRemider: function () {
      this.$emit("toggleReminda");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The parent component looks like this:

*src/components/TaskList.vue*

```
<template>
  <div class="padding-end">
    <Task
      v-for="(task, index) in info"
      @toggleReminda="convertRemind(task)"
      :title="task.title"
      :date="task.date"
      :reminder="task.reminder.toString()"
      :key="task.id"
      :id="task.id"
      v-on:askToDeleteTask2="deleteTask"
      v-on:askToUpdateTask2="askToUpdateTask3"
      :taskColor="getGradientColors(index)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Task from "./Task.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import Gradient from "javascript-color-gradient";

export default {
  name: "TaskList",
  components: {
    Task,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
      colours: [],
      colourPairs: [],
    };
  },
  props: {
    taskData: Object,
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/tasks").then((response) => {
      this.info = response.data;
      let colorGradient = new Gradient();
      const color1 = "#FFC300";
      const color2 = "#C7003A";

      colorGradient.setMidpoint(this.info.length * 2);
      colorGradient.setGradient(color1, color2);
      this.colours = colorGradient.getArray();
    });
  },
  computed: {},
  beforeUpdate() {},
  methods: {
    deleteTask: function (id) {
      axios
        .delete(`http://localhost:3000/tasks/${id}`)
        .then(() => {
          this.info = this.info.filter((task) => {
            return task.id !== id;
          });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    askToUpdateTask3: function (id) {
      let taskToUpdate = this.info.filter((task) => task.id == id);
      this.$emit("askToUpdateTask4", taskToUpdate);
    },
    convertRemind: function (task) {
      if (task.reminder == "false") {
        task.reminder = "true";
      } else {
        task.reminder = "false";
      }
    },
    getGradientColors: function (index) {
      while (this.colours.length > 0) {
        this.colourPairs.push(this.colours.splice(0, 2));
      }
      return this.colourPairs[index];
    },
    sortList: function () {
      this.info.reverse();
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.padding-end:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The error says `itTrueSet`. But your variable is defined as `isTrueSet`. Is this a typo in the question? Or have you referenced the variable elsewhere in your code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-haze-kjd88?file=/src/components/Task.vue - I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. The error gets called 7 times, so I have included the parent component TaskList that renders 7 Task components. I have updated post to show the full error message from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in Task.vue `<div class="left-task-content" :class="{ adjust: itTrueSet }">`

As pointed out in the comments, you have `itTrueSet` there, when it should be `isTrueSet`. (`is` instead of `it`)